# Display parameter value for 3D data in ImageView

Tags: pyqtgraph

This example ships with the module:

[image: screenshot]

How can I know the exact value of parameter (marked in red) on bottom slider?
It doesn't matter the way to get there - either as a tooltip or as a value drawn on screen etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to access this information:

```
imv = pg.ImageView()
i = imv.currentIndex  # the currently-displayed frame
z = imv.timeLine.Value()  # gives access to the line position
```

You can also connect a callback to detect when the value has changed:

```
imv.timeLine.sigPositionChanged.connect(myCallback)
```

It's up to you to decide how the value should be displayed, though (tooltip, label, etc.)